# Does Spark's TwitterUtils library captures all the twitters?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming

I am using Spark's Twitterutils library to work with the twitters. However, I'm getting on average only like 60 twitters per second, while there must be far more twitters per second. So, it seems like the TwitterUtils library is not capturing all the twitters. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not linked to Spark's library, but to Twitter limitation to the stream. If you use public Twitter stream, you are limited to 1% of the global traffic, which is around 60 tweets/seconds.

If you want unlimited access you need to subscribe to paid services, like Gnip (http://www.gnip.com ) which is a Twitter subsidiary.

Comment: That sucks. However, now I now the reason. Thanks for telling :). Any idea how much these paid services cost?

Comment: Yes, but probably more that you are willing to pay! ;) The best is to contact Gnip directly....